# Указатель на функтор

Tags: c++, указатели

У меня есть следующие классы:

```
class A {
public:
    B* b;
}

class B {
public:
    double operator()(double val);
}
```

Дальше я в какой-то момент пытаюсь вызвать класс `B` как функцию через указатель на класс `A`:

```
a->b(val); //a - указатель на экземпляр класса A
```

При компиляции я получаю ошибку:

```
error: 'A::b' cannot be used as a function
```

Вопрос: как это исправить? Т.е. как использовать функторы по указателю?

Comment: `(a->b)(val)` - то же самое

Comment: А, погодите-ка, у вас же там **указатель** на `B`, а не просто `B`. Стрелочка разыменовывает только `a`. Нет компилятора под рукой, нет возможности проверить.

Comment: Точно. Если явно разыменовать все, то компилируется: `(*(a->b))(val)`. Спасибо.

Comment: О, вы и сами справились. Оформите и ответ тогда уж =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и так:

```
a->b->operator()(val);
```

если `a` - указатель на `A`.

Если же, как вы написали в вопросе, *//a - экземпляр класса A*, то тогда

```
(*a.b)(val);
a.b->operator()(val);
```

Судя по вашему ответу на свой вопрос, вы все же ошиблись в самом вопросе, и `a` у вас - указатель на экземпляр, а не сам экземпляр...

Comment: Да, действительно, ошибся в вопросе немного. Исправил.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, чтобы компилировалось, надо явно разыменовать указатель `a->b`:

```
(*(a->b))(val);   //Вместо a->b(val)
```